# OS X: Trying to find out file type of old files without extension

Tags: macos, file-type

I'm trying to find out what file type old OS 9 files without extension have.

When I open them in a text editor the all look similar to this:

```
˛7�#������$�������������K��������a����������������������������





��.
l
l
l
l
```

After this comes plain text. The only thing that's the same everywhere it the `7#` at the top of the file. At the bottom there are fonts icluded, which looks like this:

```
-:LaserWriter�
%����Chicago���New York���Geneva���Monaco���Palatino���Times��� Helvetica���Courier���Symbol��9]BI Garamond 3 BoldItalic��9^B     Garamond 3 Bold��9_I Garamond 3 Italic��9`
Garamond 3��9з CXBO Futura CondExtraBoldOblique��9иCXB Futura CondExtraBold��9йCBO Futura CondBoldOblique��9кCB Futura CondensedBold��9лCO Futura CondensedOblique��9мC Futura Condensed��9нCLO Futura CondLightOblique��9оCL Futura CondensedLight��9пXBO Futura ExtraBoldOblique��9рXB Futura ExtraBold��9сHO Futura HeavyOblique��9тH Futura Heavy��9уO Futura Oblique��9фFutura��:BO Futura BoldOblique��:
B Futura Bold��:O Futura BookOblique��:Futura Book��:LO Futura LightOblique��:L Futura Light��:ЊBI Garamond BoldItalic��:ЌB Garamond Bold��:ЋI Garamond LightItalic��:ЏGaramondЂ���c��c�Ђ�Ђ���c�����(�Х�(��ъ�Д������-��J����c��Б��В��Ъ��:��Ъ��ы��r��…�� Л��
```

��
Anyone who was there in the OS 9 days? =)

Comment: I don't think they are "printer"-files, as there are hundreds of them in an old archive folder.

Answer (score 1):

The command line tool `GetFileInfo` will list the File Type and Creator Code. You may need to search to translate this into Applications, but many are obvious.

Comment: Ok, this is a nice tool, but useless on those old files. It shows absolutely no info. But thanks for the tip.

    `type: "\0\0\0\0"
    creator: "\0\0\0\0"
    attributes: avbstclinmedz
    created: 01/01/1904 01:00:00
    modified: 01/01/1904 01:00:00`

Comment: But I found that some of those files that start with 7# are actually Word '97 files and can be converted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most of the files beginning with 7# are Word '97 files.

To convert them into newer files I'm adding the `.doc` extension and convert them using CloudConvert.org. I tried using Word 2011 but it didn't work that well.